# Safari 7.1 Bookmark not closing properly

Tags: macos, safari, bug

I sometime notice this random behaviour of the bookmarks not closing and it leaves me with something like this, any suggestions?

I'm running Mavericks with everything updated. 
[image]

Comment: is the extreme 'squariness' the symptom, or anonymising for the picture?

Comment: @Tetsujin it's anonymising =) the problem is the grey area that keeps showing until you open and close the bookmarks again.

Comment: OK, thanks, just checking. Does it do it immediately after a reboot? Have you tried with very few tabs open? [I know how many tabs you can build up over a time… & they really hit memory] My thought is it could be struggling for memory, paging to disk etc.

Comment: To be honest it's not slow and safari uses max 500 mb memory. I think it happens more at random.

Answer (score 1):

Added as answer just to provide image…

I think you might be surprised how much memory Safari can use if you view all its processes Hierarchically… a rough tot-up here gives me about 2.7 GB ...

[image]

Comment: When it occurred this was in activity monitor -> https://www.evernote.com/shard/s314/sh/039a9979-a879-498f-8c12-6327fd67aff6/cf988e31b6e5dbb27250d299739db7af